# Changing Link URL of existing <a class> using JS or otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a plugin on my site to enable quiz functionality. When a lesson/quiz has been completed by a user there is a popup that features a button with a link back to another page. The problem I have is that I need to change this link.

This is what console looks like:

[View Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1iAd.png)

I need to be able to edit the href link shown here so that I can redirect users to the correct page. Firstly I need to know if this is possible and secondly how I could go about implementing this change.

I'm presuming it can be achieved with JS, but my knowledge of JS is limited so I'm unsure about the execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change attribute `href` as simple as any other attribute:

```
$('a.gdlr-lms-button').attr('href', 'new-url');
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can do it like this.

Where `test` the classname is so just replace that by `gdlr-lms-button`

```js
$('a.test').attr('href', 'www.google.be');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='test' href="www.facebook.com">Hello</a>
```